# when use online its working correctly .. what do i have to include to make jquery work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/Kh2fz/

```
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">alert("sfd");     
 </script> 
 <script>
  var $elements = $('#fp-slides div'); 
  var total_elements = $elements.length;
  var element_with_class = 0;
  window.setInterval( function () {
$elements.eq(element_with_class).removeClass('current');
element_with_class += 1;
if ( element_with_class === total_elements )
{
  element_with_class = 0;
}

$elements.eq(element_with_class).addClass('current'); 

 }, 400 );
```

this is not working. when i compied its not working... but works just fine in online compiler..

Comment: Try wrapping that in a `$(document).ready(function() {} )` to ensure it isn't loading before the document is ready

Comment: `alert("sfd");` will never be called

Comment: alert(); is not the problem... The problem is jquery is not working... but dat alert() is working fine on the online compiler(Ex:w3schools compiler();

Comment: I know alert() is not your problem but it is still not correct and if this code is working on w3schools compiler, which i really doubt, then change urgently the way you are testing code...

Comment: Ok tested it on w3schools compiler and of course doesn't work so...

Comment: can u send some code to change class name repeatedly after 5 seconds.... like slideshow........

Comment: @user3041822 have you try suggestion in first comment here, this is your issue. Now if you have other issue irrelevant to your question, ask a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your script after the HTML and it will work!

Answer (score 0):

Download the jQuery javascript file an the css file from the jQuery website.
Then insert this code into your head section of your html site:

```
<link type="text/css" href="your path /your jQuery css file name.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
```

and for js insert:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="your path/your jQuery js file name.js"></script>
```

Look that the path is correct and keep attention for the writing.

then it should work.

greethings

Comment: Like we can see on your jsfiddle your code is working so the only thing you have to look for is the embedding of these two jquery files ;-)

Comment: OP just needs to call relevant js code once elements are present in the DOM, e.g, using document ready handler